# Can message length be useful information?

Tags: encryption, sniffing, third-party

Suppose a packet is encrypted and sent via an insecure channel so that it is intercepted by a malicious third party as well as the intended recipient. As long as a suitable encryption scheme is used, the message should be (practically) uncrackable.

However, assuming that encryption preserves message length to a certain degree, the third party *will* gain some info about the size of the message. Is there any context in which knowing only a message’s length could be useful to a hacker? If so, what are some examples?

Comment: You mean packet message length or message length in general?

Comment: Are you wondering about encryption in general or specifically encrypting TCP/IP traffic? Would an answer explaining padding in modern crypto suites be sufficient?

Comment: @schroeder Either packet length or message length. And I’m not interested in knowing *how* to prevent the third party from obtaining message length info, but rather what the third party might do with such information.

Comment: But if there is a specific defence against knowing length, wouldn't that help you understand the risks as a pointer for further research? Padding has a specific purpose that I believe is the answer that you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

While the length of a message alone is not suitable to directly extract the secrets it might be a valuable context information. If the length of the plain message alone provides useful information then the length of the encrypted message will usually not fully hide these information (only a bit due to padding). Such context is especially useful if there is not only a single message but when many messages can be observed.

The length information can for example together with timing information be used for fingerprinting traffic, like [distinguishing DNS over HTTPS from "normal" HTTPS](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Is+it+Possible+to+Identify+DNS+over+HTTPs+Without+Decrypting+TLS/25616/). With DNS over TLS it might also be possible to [narrow down which requests where done](https://faculty.sites.uci.edu/zhouli/files/2019/11/conext19.pdf) based on the length. Length information played a major part in the [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH) and [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME) attacks against TLS and HTTPS, where the visible length of the compressed and encrypted content made it possible to figure out parts of the unencrypted content.